# Swift load images asynchronously for SearchTextField

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I use the [SearchTextField](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField) library for having an AutoComplete text edit. It works like a charm but I have an issue. I have more than 200 records to list. I have to fetch all images from an URL. Thus, my code below works very slowly.

What I want to do is fetching images from the web asynchronously and run this library quickly. I found some solutions to load images asynchronously like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) and [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) but they need UIImageView, not UIImage, therefore I cannot use them.

Any idea will be appreciated.

This is my code scrap for creating SearchTextField

```
var item =  [SearchTextFieldItem]()

//I have more than 100 records in my UserList
for key in UsersList {
    var imgUser : UIImage? = nil
    let url = URL(string: key.ProfilePicture)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    if ( data == nil) {
        imgUser = UIImage(named: "UserIcon")
    } else {
        imgUser = UIImage(data:data!)
    }
    item.append(SearchTextFieldItem(title: key.Name!, subtitle: key.EMail,image: imgUser))
}

mySearchTextField.filterItems(item)
```

Comment: Never use `Data(contentsOf:)` with a remote URL, especially on the main queue. Use `URLSession` to download the data.

Comment: @rmaddy I used the `URLSession` for fetching data but I didn't find a solution to create **item.append** in `completionHandler` that's why I need a solution for this component.